# save id´s of selected element´s

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

hey there i have little list here:

```
<ul id="selectable">
<li id='id.00'></li>
<li id='id.10'></li>
<li id='id.20'></li>
<li id='id.30'></li>
<li id='id.40'></li>
<li id='id.50'></li>
<li id='id.60'></li>
<li id='id.70'></li>
<li id='id.80'></li>
<li id='id.90'></li>
</ul
```

and i am able to select one or more of those listelement´s using css:

```
ul {overflow:hidden;}
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected { background: black; color: white; }
#selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 300px; }
#selectable li {float: left; width: 30px; height: 20px; background-color: none; display:block; }
```

and now i want to save the id´s of all selected element´s using jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        stop: function() {
            var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
            $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function() {
                var index = $(this).attr('id');
                result.append( index );
                alert(index);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

ok so far so good:
When i select e.g. four listelements, they get marked, BUT: only the last id is saved.
For example, when i select this listelement´s:

```
<li id='id.00'></li>
<li id='id.10'></li>
<li id='id.20'></li>
<li id='id.30'></li>
```

only the id: "id.30" is safed in my variable "index".
How can i get my jquery to safe all id´s of selected elements and not just the last one? greetings!

Comment: Why are you using IDs for indexes like that? If you don't want to have a real data model for your business logic to back your presentation for the very list you can find the element's index using DOM methods rather than saving sequential IDs which is never good.

Comment: Using "." in "id" values is problematic.

Comment: [Seems to work for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/DW6Lc/)

Comment: @lonesomeday... when you select more than one listelement, only the last id is safed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var result = $(".ui-selected", this).map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Note: This will return `array`

---

If you want to get string use `.join()`

```
var result = $(".ui-selected", this).map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get().join(',');
```

---

Updated after OP's comment

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/DW6Lc/22/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
        stop: function () {
            var result = $(".ui-selected", this).map(function () {
                return this.id;
            }).get().join(',');
            $('#select-result').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for joining this issue, i tried it: http://jsfiddle.net/DW6Lc/11/ but i cant get a result, you know why? greetings